# Visa for Australia - day count for eVisitor (subclass 651)

Tags: visas, australia, german-citizens, visa-expiration

I'm from Germany and I visit Australia for traveling only. 
This is my timetable for visiting (24h time format, DD.MM.YYYY):

- 09.10.2017, 08:55: Flight from Amsterdam via Munich to Hong Kong
- 10.10.2017, 09:00: Start Flight Hong Kong to Brisbane
- 10.10.2017, 20:50: Landing in Brisbane
- 08.01.2018, 19:50: Start Flight from Sydney to Christchurch
- 09.01.2018, 00:25: Flight from Sydney to Christchurch

I plan to use the eVisitor (subclass 651) which allows me to stay for three months (https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-listing/evisitor-651).

- Does this means I can stay for 3 months day to day e.g. 10.10.17 - 10.01.2018 or "just" 90 days?
- When is the start and end date of the visa? Does it start when I arrive and ends when I leave?

Comment: Add added some infos about the format and checked the flights again, i missread the timetable with the timezones and fixed it in my post. sorry about that. the flight from hong kong is a direct flight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Three months" means three calendar months.

Based on the itinerary above, the visa will start on 10 October 2017 (the day you enter Australia) and expires on 10 January 2018 (three months after the day you enter Australia).  The time of day is ignored.

Once you have entered Australia, you can use the [VEVO](http://www.border.gov.au/Busi/visas-and-migration/visa-entitlement-verification-online-(vevo)) service to check the exact date the visa will expire.

Answer (score 1):

EVisitor visa is multiple entry, you can stay in australia for up to 3 months at a time. Within the year of validity you can enter all the wishes you want. On the [Australian government's website](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-listing/electronic-travel-authority-601) you will find all the information.